# How do I make an SKSpriteNode appear on the other side of the screen if it touches the border?

Tags: ios, sprite, sprite-kit, accelerometer, skspritenode

I'm using the accelerometer and I want to create the illusion that if the sprite node touches for example the left border of the screen, it should display the remaining part of the node on the right border.
The solutions I've come up with, only "teleported" the sprite node to the other side of the screen, but it should flow naturally..

nvm found a simple solution to my problem:
if the sprite node ends up outside the screen +x pixels the new position of the sprite will be [other side of screen]

Comment: You can add another node on the other side that folows the first ones movement on the other side

Comment: Create a physics boundary representing the edge. Detect a collision. Add an action that changes the position.